# How to export Calibre's library for Database Support?

Tags: data-synchronization, books, postgresql, quality, ebook

I have used Calibre but I would like get more freedom in exporting it elsewhere for edits.
I would like to do quality assurance of my books, papers and literature. 
Calibre does not communicate with database systems like MySQL, PostgeSQL and Oracle, discussed [here](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-84167.html).
I would like to bind Calibre to PostgreSQL to do the data verification of each document in database. 
I think the best way would be to export Calibre´s library.

How can you export Calibre's library?

Comment: What sort of edits?

Comment: @Mark I added better description. I would like to do the quality assurance of the documents. However, there is no database connection to the software which is causing big problems. The only way to do it is export the library elsewhere.

Comment: I am still confused - calibre is based on SQLite for the library - the documents are in the file system and what do you mean by QA?

Comment: @Mark QA about the search capability, for instance. To built external tables to support the library. To test search characteristics of documents systematically with the library.

Answer (score 1):

Calibre is based around a SQLite database so you can do SQL work including adding tables on it directly - I think calibre only creates extra tables with books_ or custom_ as a prefix so your own tables would not be affected by it.

Extra fields can be added which appear in the GUI to be extra fields in the Book table but are actually each in tables with a 1-1 mapping to the Books table

To extract data any sql tool can be used including the command line sqlite which Apple includes in OS X .

There are plugins like [Multi Column search](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=261712) that allow more complex searches to be done.

Comment: Is there anyone here who is doing such an QA here? This should be a part of any research work regularly/daily.

Comment: What do you mean by QA?

Comment: QA is Quality Assurance. I want to check the OCR of the file. Test how fast it is with specific test searches. See if I need to integrate Search capability to it afterwards with an external layer; again test it. Further, extension possibilities too.

Comment: So add fields to the calibre schema using the preferences